# Self-signed SSL certificate to match multiple subdomains

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I have a bunch of sites served through nginx with SSL with self-signed certificates, each of which is on a subdomain, e.g.:

```
https://app1.example.com
https://app2.example.com
```

My user base is small and tightly controlled so I personally install the certificates for each user.  The problem is that the number of apps is increasing to the point that it would be far easier to be able have a single `*.example.com` which I circulate.  However, self-signed wildcard certificates don't work in most browsers.  How would I get around this?  I'm guessing that one option would be to somehow provide a list of subdomains for the certificate, but I have no idea how I would go about doing that.  My other thought is that perhaps I could create a self-signed root certificate from which each subdomain inherits?

Comment: If your userbase is indeed well controlled the most convenient might be to set up your own PKI (or really just a CA), distribute that new root CA certificate and then create signed certificates as needed.

Comment: You could create a GPO to push all certificate too if the PC are in a domain. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770315%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @HBruijn I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but it sounds like what I want.  Could you expand on the answer and give any guidance as to how to do it?

Comment: @yagmoth555  Controlled group of users, but not all on the same domains, and the domains are not in my control.

Comment: Setting up a CA with openssl from a  command line is quite well documented. See for instance [this](http://math.cmu.edu/~svasey/old-homepage-archive-2013/projects/software-usage-notes/ssl_en.html) site, `man ca`

Answer (score 0):

If your user base and their computers are not managed by you, then that is a classic case where you should purchase an SSL certificate from a 3rd party rather than use self-signed certs. Wildcard certs are readily available from many 3rd party CAs and they are not very expensive.  I assume you own the example.com domain.